# Join from a table(CategoryStores) of 24k records taking a longer time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select distinct StoreUID,

       STOCode,
       STODescription,
       STODateOfBirth,
       STOLevel,
       RGNDescription as [Region],
       RGNOrder,
       STOActive,
       STOAreaSqFeet,
       STOTotalSqFeet,
       STOModifiedDate,
       STOModifiedBy,

          case when
           isnull(STCCompM1,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM2,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM3,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM4,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM5,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM6,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM7,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM8,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM9,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM10,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM11,'N')='Y' or
           isnull(STCCompM12,'N')='Y'or
           isnull(STCCompM13,'N')='Y' then 1 else 0 end as CompStore
from [Store]

cross join #CategoryStores plcat             
inner join [Region] on RegionUID=STORegionUID                                                                                 
inner join UserStores us on us.USTStoreUID = StoreUID and us.USTUserUID=@UserUID  

inner join **CategoryStores** cs on plcat.CategoryUID = cs.CSTCategoryUID and StoreUID = cs.CSTStoreUID    

left outer join StoreComp on STCStoreUID=StoreUID and STCYear=@BudgetYear - 1  
where STOActive = 1  
order by  STOCode
```

There are only two foreign key columns in CategoryStores(CSTCategoryUID bigint, CSTStoreUID bigint).    This is taking 40 seconds join with CategoryStores and without only 2 secs. How will i improve the performance?

Comment: create an indexes on needed columns. I believe that if you see the explain plan (ctrl+L) for that query then SSMS would suggest you the proper indexes

Comment: btw you can change your ISNULLs in your case statements for the single line expression: COALESCE(STCCompM1, STCCompM2,..., STCCompM13, 'N') = 'Y'

Comment: try to create INDEX for #CategoryStores or try using CROSS APPLY

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Using `coalesce` changes the semantics. If `STCCompM1 = 'N'` and `STCCompM2 = 'Y'` then the OP's logic returns `1`. Yours would return `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the foreign keys that are used for the inner join connection, are indexed properly.

Moreover, try to use [Cross Apply](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) in order to improve performance of your query for example:

instead of

```
inner join [Region] on RegionUID = STORegionUID
```

you can use:

```
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT TOP (1) FROM [Region]
     WHERE [Region].RegionUID = [Store].STORegionUID) ca
```

Read more about cross apply in the attached link.